# Show branch names with "git log --graph --oneline --decorate" when it takes a filename

Tags: git, git-log

### Background

- Our team uses a git repository on GitLab to store source files of a product.
- We are using a git-flow-like branch model to commit and merge changes to the repository.
- I found that some feature branches are not merged unintentionally. Also, there are some feature branches that should be deleted like:

  - Branches that merged to the develop branch successfully and not deleted yet
  - Branches that abandoned (because they can't be merged successfully)
- I want to distinguish branches that should be merged from ones that should be deleted.

### What I want to do

To confirm that all the necessary changes are merged to the develop branch successfully, I am trying to show a merge graph per file like this:

```sh
git log --graph --all --oneline --decorate=full develop -- ./path/to/a/file
```

And if there is a file that forked and not merged like this, I want to ask the owner of the file to merge or delete the branch that contains that file.

```
* 4151fa9 Commit Message 4
| * 8dc5658 Commit Message 3
* | d579006 Commit Message 2
|/  
* 4df043a Commit Message 1
```

### Problem

I want to know the name of the branch that forked and not merged (`8dc5658` in above), but `git log --graph --oneline --decorate` doesn't show the branch name if it takes a file name as its argument.

What I want to get as the result of `git log --graph --all --oneline --decorate=full develop -- ./path/to/a/file` is like this:

```
* 4151fa9 (HEAD -> develop) Commit Message 4
| * 8dc5658 (branch-abandoned) Commit Message 3
* | d579006 Commit Message 2
|/  
* 4df043a Commit Message 1
```

### Question

How can I show the branch name in the result of `git log --graph --oneline --decorate` when it takes a file name as its argument?

Note that you can show an original branch for a commit with `git branch --contains COMMIT`, but it's difficult to identify commits to pass to `git branch --contains` from a commit graph (`4151fa9` and `8dc5658` in the above) for each file in the repository.

Comment: Just tried `git log --graph --oneline --decorate -15 -- <some file>` in a repo I have at hand. Works like a charm, decorations *are* included in output. Can it be that your filtered commits happen not to have tags/branches pointing at them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `--simplify-by-decoration` :

```
# note : if you use '--all', you don't need to add 'develop'
git log --graph --all --oneline --simplify-by-decoration -- path/to/a/file
```

you will get :

- all commits that are tagged with a branch or a tag (or any ref actually)
- and all commits that modify in some way `path/to/a/file`

---

If you don't want to see all the possible refs drawn in your graph, you may use `--decorate-refs` :

```
# will only show local branches :
git log ... --decorate-refs=refs/heads

# will only show 'origin/master' and local tags :
git log ... --decorate-refs=refs/remotes/origin/master --decorate-refs=refs/tags
```

Answer (score 0):

To confirm that all the necessary changes are merged to the develop branch successfully you can use double-dot syntax, ex.

`git log master..experiment`

If you have get a list of commits that means that you have commits in your experiment branch that hasn’t yet been merged into your **master** branch and if you don't get any commit in the output means that the master branch has all the commits that the **experiment** has.
For more details see https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection  **Double Dot** part.